# js equal array of objects are not equal

Tags: javascript

I am getting obj A from mongo using `findOne`.
Then trying to compare obj `A.test` with obj `B.test` (which is a req.body).
.test is an array of objects.

```
var objA = await DB.findOne({...});
var objB = req.body;
console.log(objA.test)
// [ { key_value: 'aaa', key_name: '111' },
//   { key_value: 'bbb', key_name: '222' } ]

console.log(objB.test)
// [ { key_name: '111', key_value: 'aaa' },
//   { key_name: '222', key_value: 'bbb' } ]
var result = isEqual(objA.test,objB.test);

console.log(result) //false


var one = [{ key_value: 'aaa', key_name: '111' },
    { key_value: 'bbb', key_name: '222' }]
var two = [{ key_name: '111', key_value: 'aaa' },
    { key_name: '222', key_value: 'bbb' }]

  
console.log(isEqual(one,two)) //true


var isEqual = function(a,b){
return _(a).differenceWith(b, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
}
```

Can anyone make any sense of this? Is object returned by mongo actualy not what it prints? If so is there a way to 'convert' objA into a 'normal' array of objects?
I have tried to JSON.stringify(objA.test) and objB.test then using lodash _.isEqual(a,b) but no luck as the order of key_name,_key_value is not the same. If I were to 'reinvent the wheel' and manually compare these obj, how would it be done? Thanks!

Comment: That is because you are comparing mongoDB object with req.body. use `DB.findOne({...}).lean()` will solve your problem I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.lean()` after `DB.findOne({...})` worked like mentioned By Shubham Kumar